# Adding line graphs adjacent to each other in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, charts

I have a set of data that is grouped by both "Male and Female", and also three different time periods across three different conditions (labeled dft, dt, and ft).  Here is the data:

[image: data]

I would like to show this data as set of line graphs, but only across each group of three time periods. As such, I hope to produce a figure with six different lines, one male and one female for each set of 3 line graphs.

I hope for it to look something like this:

[image: this]

Can this be accomplished in Excel? If that is not possible, could it be produced in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scott was almost there. A modification to the data layout, and it's done.

In the data range below, I have staggered the sets of data, so there are actually three series each for Male and Female. This provides the gaps between major groupings without requiring excess spaces (extra columns). Alternatively, you could select the individual line segments in each series and format as no line, but that's tedious.

Then you just need to format all the Male series the same and all the female series the same. Then one by one, select the redundant legend entries (to select: click once to select the legend, then again to select the legend entry) and click Delete.

If you really want the lines between sections (between major groupings), let me know and I'll show you how to do that. But a gap in the lines should be sufficient.

Also, no need to merge the headers in row 1. Leave them like this, or if you want the appearance of merged cells without the severe drawbacks, select B1:J1, right-click, and choose Format Cells from the pop-up. Click on the alignment tab, and under Horizontal choose Center Across Selection.

[image: Line Panel Chart]

Comment: Good job! But I’ll raise you one: [you can leave the “ft” data in ``H3:J4``](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lguzq.png).

Comment: @Scott - Sure, I almost did it that way. Six of one...

Answer (score 1):

I was able to come close to what you want just by

- Adding a blank column before and after each condition.
- Merging the headers on row 1 to `B1:F1`, `G1:K1` and `L1:P1`.
- Creating a Line chart.

[image: three Line charts side-by-side within a chart in Excel]

Unfortunately the blank columns of data
are reflected as blank columns in the chart.